# Why my Bar Button item isn't getting hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I'm using `UIBarButtonItem` in my project. I've tried to hide the `UIBarButtonItem` in iOS 6.1, but I was unable to do the same using the following code:

```
barbuttonname.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
barbuttonname.enabled = NO;
```

This code hides the `UIBarButtonItem` in iOS 7.1, but in iOS 6.0 it shows the `UIBarButtonItem`. How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because use of `tintColor` for that purpose only became available in iOS 7. in iOS 6, the buttons also typically have borders and backgrounds and each bit is handled separately. In terms of what you're actually trying to accomplish here, I think you should go about it a different way.

Instead of modifying properties on the button to hide it, simply remove it from the navigation bar or wherever you have it. For example, if it is the right button on a `UINavigationBar`, you would just do:

```
myNavigationBar.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Then, when you want to show it again

```
myNavigationBar.rightBarButtonItem = myButtonItem;
```